# Reading rest service of content type application/vnd.oracle.adf.resourceitem+json

Tags: java, web-services, rest, http-headers, oracle-adf

I have a webservice whose content type is **application/vnd.oracle.adf.resourceitem+json**.

The HttpEntity of the reponse obtained by hitting this service is looks like this

```
ResponseEntityProxy{[Content-Type: application/vnd.oracle.adf.resourceitem+json,Content-Length: 3,Chunked: false]}
```

When I try to convert this HttpEntity into String it gives me a blank String `{}`.

Below are the ways I tried to convert the `HttpEntity` to `String`

1.

`String strResponse = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());`

2.

```
String strResponse = "";
String inputLine;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()));
try {
    while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(inputLine);
        strResponse += inputLine;
    }
    br.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

3.

```
response.getEntity().writeTo(new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\harshita.sethi\\Documents\\Chabot\\post.txt")));
```

All returns String -> `{}`.

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Is this because of the content type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code is still giving the same response with empty JSON object. So I modified and wrote the below code. This one seems to run perfectly fine.

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.addRequestProperty("Authorization", getAuthToken());
con.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/vnd.oracle.adf.resourceitem+json;charset=utf-8");

String input = String.format("{\"%s\":\"%s\",\"%s\":\"%s\"}", field, value, field2, value2);

System.out.println(input);
OutputStream outputStream = con.getOutputStream();
outputStream.write(input.getBytes());
outputStream.flush();

con.connect();
System.out.println(con.getResponseCode());
// Uncompressing gzip content encoding
GZIPInputStream gzip = new GZIPInputStream(con.getInputStream());

StringBuffer szBuffer = new StringBuffer();

byte tByte[] = new byte[1024];

while (true) {
    int iLength = gzip.read(tByte, 0, 1024);

    if (iLength < 0) {
        break;
    }

    szBuffer.append(new String(tByte, 0, iLength));
}
con.disconnect();

returnString = szBuffer.toString();
```

Authentication method

```
private String getAuthToken() {
        String name = user;
        String pwd = this.password;
        String authString = name + ":" + pwd;
        byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(authString.getBytes());
        System.out.println(new String(authEncBytes));
        return "Basic " + new String(authEncBytes);
    }
```

In case anybody faces the same issue. Let me share the challenged I faced and how I rectified those.

The above code works for all content-types/methods. Can be used for any type (GET, POST, PUT,DELETE).
For my requirement I had a POST webservice with

**Content-Encoding →gzip**

**Content-Type →application/vnd.oracle.adf.resourceitem+json**

**Challenges :** I was able to get the correct response code  but I was getting junk characters as my response string.

**Solution :** This was because the output was compressed in `gzip` format which needed to be uncompressed.

The code of uncompressing the `gzip content encoding` is also mentioned above.

Hope it helps future users.